# Realtek High Definition Audio - No Sound/Static Noise

Tags: audio, motherboard, operating-systems

I recently built a PC with components below. The audio jack was working fine with my headphones until yesterday, and then it stopped working. (more clarification: OS/Motherboard recognize the integrated audio card, even recognize when a device is connected/disconnected. But all I can hear is static noise) Things that happened between the last time I had them working, and today (those changes that I think may be relevant):

1. Reinstalled windows 10
2. Installed NVMe SSD
3. Plugged in a new monitor through DisplayPort.
4. Set up hyper-v VM/install hyper-v  manager/created virtual network switch (internal/external)

(Not In Order)

The timeline as to when it stopped working is not clear to me, because I only use my headphones when playing a game or watching a video. And I was mostly working yesterday, so I'm not sure whether the issue started after or before the changes mentioned above.

computer components:

Motherboard: MSI B350 Tomohawk  - updated as of the latest available

CPU: Ryzen 1700

Storage:

DISK 0: SATA

DISK 1: SATA

DISK 2: NVMe SSD M.2 (Key M)

Wireless: TP-Link PCI

OS: Windows 10 v1703 Pro - Up to date

What I tried:

1. Updated motherboard
2. Updated Realtor Driver (Both from MB manufacturer, and Realtek Codec)
3. Tried W10 Generic Audio Driver
4. Uninstaled, installed, enabled, disabled HD Audio on OS and BIOS level.
5. Tried clean boot, disabling any third party services.
6. Made sure Realtek recognizes device, and device is set as default. Testing shows the bar playing audio, but no sound.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Boot from a Live CD running an OS capable of sending audio to your headphones to determine if hardware or software/OS/drivers are the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine if the problem is caused by hardware or software. One way to do that is boot from a Live CD running an OS capable of sending audio to your headphones.

If the audio works, your hardware is good and you need to pursue the problem assuming an issue with the main OS or drivers. If it doesn't work, then the hardware is defective and needs replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I did what Twisty and some other suggested, and booted up ubuntu on a usb to see if I can replicate the issue. Still no sound, so I am certain it's hardware issue. I'll be getting a replacement motherboard thanks to Amazon.